# Search for file in folder backwards

Tags: vb.net, search

So far all the examples for checking if a file is in a directory has been to get a list of files in that directory then compare your items to it. This is a lot of overload for me. I have a list of about 125 files and the directory I want to search in has 8000 files. Can someone instruct me on how to use a file with a list of file names and search a directory for each file.

*Moved here from comments:*

> The code below works, but because it's searching through 8000 files in
>   a directory the code takes a long time to work. I have a document with
>   350 lines of file names. Instead of going through each file in the
>   directory for a match to one of the file names in my document. I'd
>   like to take my list and search the directory for that file. This way
>   I'm only looping 350 times instead of 8000

Here is my code.

```
    Dim fileNames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imgLocation)

    Dim i As Integer
    statusText = "Copying Image Files"
    i = 0
    ' Loop over the filenames retrieved
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames

        ' Check if the files is contained or not in the request list
        If GraphicList.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)) Then

            'Debug.Write("Filename " & fileName & vbCr)
            Dim FileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
            Dim copyTo As String
            copyTo = createImgFldr & "\" & FileNameOnly
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, copyTo, True)

            ' Do not write to file inside the loop, just add the fact to the list
            ' Debug.Write("Copy image " & FileNameOnly & vbCr)

            imgFilename = (FileNameOnly) + vbCrLf
            ImageCount1 = i

            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 * i / GraphicList.Count())
            foundImgFiles.Add(FileNameOnly)
        Else
            Debug.Write("Missing " & FileNameOnly & vbCr)
            notfoundImgFiles.Add(fileName)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

Comment: Can you please explain what issue's you are having with the code above? Are there errors, logic issues, etc? Currently there's no explanation of what you are experiencing, so it will make it hard to *guess* what may be wrong. `Can someone instruct me on how to use a file with a list of file names and search a directory for each file`, it seems you are *asking* us to do it for you...

Comment: The code above works. But because it's searching through 8000 files in a directory the code takes a long time to work. I have a document with 350 lines of file names. Instead of going through each file in the directory for a match to one of the file names in my document. I'd like to take my list and search the directory for that file. This way I'm only looping 350 times instead of 8000

Comment: `The code above works` if that's the case, please check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as this would be best. There you could explain just like you did in this post and include the comment from above. There they could help *improve* your process.

Comment: I moved your comment above (into your OP) as it explains in more detail, please feel free to edit if you would like.

Comment: 1) Create a [`Dictionary(Of String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) from `fileNames`, where you associate the filename without extension with its path. 2) Loop over `GraphicList` (I assume this is where your image files are in) instead of `fileNames` and query the dictionary for existence and get the path.

Comment: I don't think you can improve the speed significantly by looping the other way. The main culprit that slows down the process is the file copy process. No matter if you loop over the 350 items or the 8000 items, the copy process still will be done on those 350 files.